# $hh \to hh$ scattering

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, higgs, scattering-cross-section

I'm trying to compute the double Higgs scatter in QFT framework. Is it correct if I use the scalar propagator for this process?

Also I've found that I've four possible diagrams: the three $s,t,u$ channels and the point, $x$ like diagram.
So when I try to do the $M$ amplitude I get a something that goes like the inverse product of difference between each Mandlestam variable and the mass of the higgs squared.

Unfortunately in my book I don't find any results to check my calculations.

Comment: Is https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.01272.pdf useful?

Comment: Yes thank you a lot !